# Detect mobile device movements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, mobile

### Using: Next.JS 14.0.4; iPhone 14

I need to detect if and how user moves his phone using **`React.JS`** (I'm using Next.JS 14.0.4). For this purpose I began looking for some libraries that can detect it with gyroscope or accelerometer and reached **[Shake.js](https://github.com/alexgibson/shake.js/)**, **[Motion sensors](https://www.w3.org/2019/04/web-roadmaps/mobile/sensors.html)**, and default **JS** event **[devicemotion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/devicemotion_event)**

For every library or event I wrote a code by the example provided on corresponding site.

### Some code

**`Shake.js:`**

```js
"use client"

import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Shake from 'shake.js';

export default function Home() {
  const [shakeDetected, setShakeDetected] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const shakeEvent = new Shake({ threshold: 15, timeout: 1000 });

    shakeEvent.start();

    window.addEventListener('shake', shakeHandler, false);

    return () => {
      shakeEvent.stop();
      window.removeEventListener('shake', shakeHandler, false);
    };
  }, []);

  const shakeHandler = () => {
    setShakeDetected(true);
    setTimeout(() => setShakeDetected(false), 5000); // Reset after 5 seconds
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Shake Detection</h1>
      {shakeDetected ? <p>Shake detected!</p> : <p>Shake your device...</p>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

**`Motion sensors:`**

```js
"use client";

import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import styles from "./page.module.css";
import { Accelerometer } from "motion-sensors-polyfill";

export default function Home() {
    const [accelerationCoords, setAccelerationCoords] = useState({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        z: 0,
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        const sensor = new Accelerometer();

        sensor.addEventListener("reading", () => {
            setAccelerationCoords({
                x: sensor.x,
                y: sensor.y,
                z: sensor.z,
            });
        });

        sensor.start();

        return () => {
            sensor.stop();
        };
    }, []);

    return <main className={styles.main}>
        <p>{accelerationCoords.x}</p>
        <p>{accelerationCoords.y}</p>
        <p>{accelerationCoords.z}</p>
    </main>;
}
```

**`devicemotion:`**

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export default function Home() {
  const [motion, setMotion] = useState({ x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 });

  useEffect(() => {
    function handleDeviceMotion(event) {
      setMotion({
        x: event.accelerationIncludingGravity.x,
        y: event.accelerationIncludingGravity.y,
        z: event.accelerationIncludingGravity.z,
      });
    }

    window.addEventListener('devicemotion', handleDeviceMotion);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('devicemotion', handleDeviceMotion);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Device Motion</h1>
      <p>X: {motion.x}</p>
      <p>Y: {motion.y}</p>
      <p>Z: {motion.z}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Then I started host with `"devip": "next dev -H 0.0.0.0 -p 8080"` (I insert my ip instead 0.0.0.0) and then connect to the host both from desktop browser and from phone (tried both Safari and Chrome).

### Result

No matter how much I shake my phone completely nothing happens. I tried to change setState in each block manually like:

```
setShakeDetected(true);
```

inside each event listener and it does not change this state